# Do I need transit visa

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, schengen-visas

Travelling via Lufthansa. Moscow to Strasbourg but all by plane.
Moscow to Frankfurt by plane then Frankfurt to Strasbourg by bus.
I have a visa for France, do I need a transit visa for Germany ?

My friend tells me that my first destination must be France, but the ticket is half price if I will travel with entering into the Schengen area in Frankfurt, but the problem is that the ticket "Frankfurt to Strasbourg is by Lufthansa bus.

Comment: There are several questions about whether your first entry into the Schengen zone needs to be your visa country. The short answer is No, as long as you can proof your onward travel, you are good to enter in an other Schengen country. One exception, some very rare visa might be for one country only, instead of all Schengen states.

Answer (score 7):

Unless your situation is exceptionally unusual, you don't have a "visa for France". You have a visa *for all the Schengen states* which happens to be *issued* by France.

When you applied for this visa, you documented a certain trip you have planned. You're supposed to do that trip more or less how you told in the application you would, or you risk your visa being revoked as having been issued on false pretenses. But "more or less" does cover reasonable variations in how you arrange to get yourself from point A to B, as long as points A and B are what you claimed they would be. A stopover in Frankfurt is completely fair game, and whether part of your travel within the area is by bus or by air does not matter either.

In summary: A short-stay visa issued by France **is valid** for entering the Schengen Area in Germany and continuing towards your main destination in France by ground transport.

The friend who tells you that you must enter the Schengen area through the country that issued your visa is *simply wrong*.